# 'Unable to find an entry point named 'OpsConIsDRCPEnabled' in DLL 'OraOps12.dll' - Oracle 12c

Tags: c#, oracle, dll

The application just upgrade to Oracle 12.2.0.1.  Download Oracle 12.2.0.1 client and also tried the ODAC122010Xcopy_x64.zip but error out the same message "'Unable to find an entry point named 'OpsConIsDRCPEnabled' in DLL 'OraOps12.dll' "

Also added OraOps12.dll to the output folder too.''

Here is the trace stacks

```
'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'E:\XYZ\New\MsSource\bin\Debug\ApplicationXYZ.nlog.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'E:\XYZ\New\MsSource\bin\Debug\ApplicationXYZ.common.dao.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'E:\XYZ\New\MsSource\bin\Debug\ApplicationXYZ.model.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Created ConMan in NcscRendererBase, DBName = XYZ user = logging, PW = if7zW46qvjs=, Rac = False
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.122.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in ApplicationXYZ.dbaccess.dll
```

An exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in ApplicationXYZ.dbaccess.dll but was not handled in user code
Unable to find an entry point named 'OpsConIsDRCPEnabled' in DLL 'OraOps12.dll'.

Any suggestion how to resolve this issue?

Comment: From control panel : Administrative Tools : ODBC Data Source : Drivers. Make sure the version of Oracle driver is compatible with the Updated Version of Oracle.  You probably have to install new version of ODBC driver.  Also you may need to force VS to recompile dirver with new dll.  So I would make a copy of project bin folder then delete to force a complete rebuild.  The compiler dependency doesn't recognize library updates.

Comment: Why this error has anything to do with ODBC data source driver?  I use ODAC or ODP.NET

Comment: How do you think the connection to Oracle is made?  What driver does ODAC and ODP.NET is using?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is here:

> Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_**4.122.1.0**__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'
>
> Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_**4.121.2.0**__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'

Looks like your upgrade to 12.2 was not properly done. Version of `OraOps12.dll` seems to mismatch with version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`

Check carefully with `gacutil.exe` what is installed in your GAC. You can configure GAC properly with these command (pick the lines which are relevant for you)

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x64\odp.net
set OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.1\Client_x86\odp.net
set OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll

IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll

IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.111.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\2.x\Policy.2.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll

IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.112.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.121.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
IF EXIST "%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll" "%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:gac /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\PublisherPolicy\4\Policy.4.122.Oracle.DataAccess.dll
```

Instead of `OraProvCfg.exe` you can also use `gacutil.exe` if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you !! use Gacutil.exe is the correct approach. Problem solved.

Comment: you saved my day. i used the exact script that you posted here - without gacutil. worked like a charm.